# Vue 3 Event Bus with Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, event-bus, vue-composition-api

I have setup [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) and trying to dispatch event to another component but I am having hard time because in the `setup()` method it doesn't have `this` for accessing app instance.

Here is what I tried:

```
import App from './App.vue'
const el = document.getElementById('app')

import mitt from 'mitt';
const emitter = mitt();

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
app.mount(el);
```

And in the component, I want to dispatch an event

```
export default {
   setup() {
      function toggleSidebar() {
          this.emitter.emit('toggle-sidebar');

          console.log(this); // binds to setup(), not the vue instance.
      }
   }
}
```

As `this` doesn't exist, I can't access the `.emitter`. What am I missing? How to use officially suggested mitt in Vue 3 composition api?

---

By the way if I use the v2 syntax, I can access `this.emitter`. But I am curious about Composition API way

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.emitter); // works
  }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To use an event bus in Vue 3 Composition API, use Vue 3's new [`provide`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-provide) api in *main.js*, and then [`inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-inject) in any component:

**1. Install [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt):**

```js
npm install mitt
```

**2. Provide:**

*main.js*

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import mitt from 'mitt';                  // Import mitt
const emitter = mitt();                   // Initialize mitt

const app = createApp(App);
app.provide('emitter', emitter);          // ✅ Provide as `emitter`
app.mount('#app');
```

**3. Inject**

3a. *Any Component* - **Emit** an event

```
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const emitter = inject('emitter'); // Inject `emitter`
    const mymethod = () => {
      emitter.emit('myevent', 100);
    };
    return {
      mymethod
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Call `mymethod` from a button click or something.</sup>

3b. *Any Component* - **Listen** for the event

```
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const emitter = inject('emitter');   // Inject `emitter`

    emitter.on('myevent', (value) => {   // *Listen* for event
      console.log('myevent received!', `value: ${value}`);
    });
  },
}
```

*Console*

```
myevent received! value: 100
```

Comment: mitt is very useful. any decoupled scripts can be seamlessly
coupled with vue3 component using mitt eventbus and this helped for a modular scripting with vue3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use `getCurrentInstance` to get the global property

component:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
export default {
  setup() {
    // get current instance
    const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance(); 
    // get the emitter from the instance
    const emitter = internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.emitter;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. Just out of curiosity, is this the right way to use with mitt and alike packages with v3?

Comment: I believe so. it's the simplest way using the app instance, alternatively you can setup an external (global) emitter.

Answer (score 2):

So far I have used this code to make the "emitter" available.

```
//main.ts
import mitt from 'mitt'
const emitter = mitt()
export default emitter
```

And then inside the components I use

```
import emitter from '@/main';
```

This worked so far in Vue2 and Vue3 - at least with the options API.

I have to admit though that I currently run into some trouble with the new vite server and the hot module reload (hmr).
Is this style suboptimal in any way?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Event Bus for Composition API you can do the following:

Install and register `mitt` in your app.js like the TS did:

```
import App from './App.vue'
const el = document.getElementById('app')

import mitt from 'mitt';
const emitter = mitt();

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
app.mount(el);
```

After that we'll move the logic for accessing global emitter to a separate file `accessEmitter.js`. I'll put it into `js/Composables` folder:

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

export default function accessEmitter() {
    return getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.emitter;
}
```

Now it can be utilized in your components:

```
<script setup>
import accessEmitter from '@/Composables/accessEmitter.js'
const emitter = accessEmitter();

// register listener
emitter.on("myEvent", (data) => {
    console.log('my event');
});
   
// remove listener
emitter.off("myEvent");

</script>
```